# How to free agents from a wait block based on same value of a integer parameter

Tags: anylogic

I have agents (of type `Segment`) with parameter `ring` (of type `int`). I want to release my agents when three rings with equal `ring` parameter have entered the `wait` block. For example the entries in `wait` block are as follows 13, 25, 7, 25, 13, 25, 13, 7, 1, 1, 7, 1...

As soon as 3 agents with the same `ring` parameter are present in the block, they should be released.
I am struggling to compare the parameters in a queue, if anybody can help that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this article does not directly answer your question, it has enough information to help you do what you need to do:

https://noorjax.com/2019/07/02/dynamic-batches/

The idea is that on each arrival, you will need to loop through the content of the queue or wait block. To do so, On Enter, you write something similar to the following:

```
List <Segment> segments = findAll(wait,s->s.ring == agent.ring );
if( segments.size() == 3 ) {
  for( Segment s : segments ) {
     self.free( s );
  }
}
```